# "object is not callable"

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying out python for a few days.
I tried to create a text editor but when i finished the code and tried to build it I get the error: `object is not callable`.

Anybody has a fix for this?

```
import tkinter   
import tkinter.filedialog    

filename = None

root = tk()
root.title("XYZ Editor")
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)

text = text(root, width=400, height=400)
text.pack()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="new", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveAs)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Error I receive is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\erwin\Desktop\Python\Test.py", line 32, in  root =
>   tk() NameError: name 'tk' is not defined [Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: Can you add the full error message. So we see which line and which objects are involved

Comment: in particular such code should not compile, you did not import "tk" or "text", only the whole library and yet call it by name inside tkinter namespace

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erwin\Desktop\Python\Test.py", line 32, in <module>
    root = tk()
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: this code doesn't seem to be compileable on python 2/3 on python 3 you get NameError: name 'tk' is not define

Comment: "not defined" is not the same as "not callable".

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this (assuming python 3):

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

Make sure Tk is uppercase.  Also make this change:

```
 text = tkinter.Text(root, width=400, height=400)
```

See http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/the_simplest_possible_Tkinter_program.

Finally, as tobias_k said, you need to define the commands such as `newFile`.  Or just comment out the following lines for now:

```
filemenu.add_command(label="new", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveAs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python 3:
Change your import from

> import tkinter

to

> from tkinter import *

and also change

> root = tk()

to

> root = Tk()

notice the capital `T` in `Tk()`.